# How to do numerical inversion of inverse laplace transform in mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to calculate the inversion Laplace transform of,

```
F(s) = Erfc[s]
at t = 100
```

I have tried the following way using Stehfest method(76 Mathematical Journal, 1994),

```
csteh[n_, i_] = (-1)^(i + n/2) Sum[k^(n/2)(2k) !/((n/2 - k) ! k ! ( k -1 ) !(i - k) !(2k - i) !), {k, Floor[(i + 1)/2], Min[i, n/2]}]; 
NLInvSteh[F_, s_, t_, n_] := log[2]/t  Sum[ csteh[n,i] F /.s -> i log[2]/t, {i, 1, n}] //N
```

My function:

```
F[s_] = Erfc[s]
%NLInvSteh[F[s], s, t, N] 
NLInvSteh[F[s], s, 100, 6]
```

The output is-

```
(Erfc[log[2.]]-49. Erfc[2. log[2.]]+366. Erfc[3. log[2.]]-858. Erfc[4. log[2.]]+810. Erfc[5. log[2.]]-270. Erfc[6. log[2.]]) log[2.]
```

Can we get the simplify value of the output.

Answer (score 0):

Use upper case `Log`.

```
NLInvSteh[F_, s_, t_, n_] := 
 Log[2]/t Sum[csteh[n, i] F /. s -> i Log[2]/t, {i, 1, n}] // N

NLInvSteh[F[s], s, 100, 6]
```

> 0.000052055

Comment: Great, it works now. Thank you for pointing the correct syntax.